Finding a constant of proportionality
I have a chemical reaction where a molecule doubles in an iterative process by the following function:
$$N = c \cdot 2^x$$
where $N$ is the resulting number of molecules, $c$ is the number of starting molecules and $x$ is the number of times the molecule doubles.
The resulting solution of molecules produced by the process is fluorescently tagged and passed by a detector, thus producing an experimental/observed integer value (call it $F_O$) between $10$ (noise) and $6000$ (saturation of the detector). Based on the model we can assume $F_O$) is proportional to $N$, therefore:
$$F_O \propto c \cdot 2^x$$
We can update the model for $N$ to calculate an expected/theoretical $F$ value ($F_E$) by multiplying the right hand side of the equation for $N$ by the amount of fluorescence contributed by one molecule (lets call it $f$):
$$F_E = c \cdot 2^x \cdot f$$
Experimentally, we've found that $F_O$ fluctuates greatly dependent upon experimental parameters outside of the model but $F$ is still solely a function of $N$ and $f$.
This all implies that:
$$F_O\propto F_E$$
What I want to do is find a proportionality constant such that:
$$F_O= F_E$$
with the explicit purpose of figuring out the fluorescent contribution of one molecule ($f$).
So at this point I'm working with:
$$\begin{equation}\tag{1}
F_O = c\cdot 2^x \cdot f \cdot k
\end{equation}$$
$$\begin{equation}\tag{2}
F_O = c \cdot 2^{x\cdot k} \cdot f \end{equation}$$
Three things I'm stuck on:

Is it possible to figure out $k$ not knowing $f$ without a second equation? I have a good estimate for the starting number of molecules and I am controlling the number of times the process doubles, so I consider these known.
What is the appropriate place for $k$ i.e. which of the above two equations is a more reasonable place for $k$, $(1)$ or $(2)$?
If this is possible, I do not know where to start. Is this some sort of differential equation problem? Or am I doing some calculus because $F_E$ is a theoretical limit?


I think you might be able to cover some ground with $F_0$. You might want to modify N though. Let $N=c_1e^{k_1x}$. Take the natural log and you get a linear expression. You can use linear regression to fit the natural log of the dependent variable. Regarding $F_E$, I'd expect that you'd need more information to get a theoretical limit. I'd expect growth to be more complicated than strictly doubling. Mass is conserved, so the parts of the new molecule come from somewhere and are probably neutral interacting with other molecules. You get a sort of herd immunity. You prob need a sigmoid curve.

Thanks for the response. You may be right and it could be an exercise in futility but if it's possible to find a good approximation for f, it could be a monumental help for interpreting our experimental data. So what you're saying is get the linear expression with a natural log but I'm still stuck on the fact I'd have two constants I'm trying to figure out the values for (f and k). ln(F) = ln(c) * kx * ln(f)...because that's what I'm really trying to find. Ln(N) = ln(c) * kx doesn't really give me any information in regard to my fluorescence values I don't already have without f.

$F_0=k\cdot 2^{px}\implies \ln F_0 = \ln k + p\cdot \ln 2 \cdot  x $. Then it looks like $f~average(F_0/N)$. $N=c\cdot 2^{x}$. $F_0/N = (k/c)2^{(p-1)x}=(k/c)e^{ (\ln 2)(p-1)x}$
$\implies f \approx (k/c) e^{(\ln 2)(p-1)x}/[(\ln 2)(p-1)]|_{x=x_1}^{x=x_2}/(x_2-x_1).$
$k$ comes from the fit, $c$ is the number of initial particles. $p$ also comes from the fit. $x_1$ is your starting $x$ value, prob 0. $x_2$ is your highest value of $x$.

Also, you're right it isn't just strictly doubling.  That's just the optimal model for what is happening and I was hoping we could find a constant to approximate the difference between an unknown theoretical limit and what we observe (ie it sounds like either a calculus or diff equation problem to me if it's possible). Basically FO = FE(k)...haha those tags didn't work there.

Woah woah slow down! lol. that's great. I have to digest that all.

Does the concept of "ingredient" apply to your model? Figure you have molecules interacting with other molecules and interacting with these ingredients. Interacting with molecules, nothing happens, they just exchange momentum. They interacting with the ingredients for making other molecules, you get other molecules. The more molecules are produced, the fewer resources or available and the more likely they are to have a non-generating interaction with fellow molecules.  I'm thinking a logistic model ight work better.

yes but those ingredients are plenty. Im just trying to create a simple underlying model to improve on what we already know.

Thanks for the assist @ultralegend5385! I couldn't figure out how to get all that formatted right!
